# How you would you detect weak negative spatial curvature that only existed in cosmic intergalactic voids?

Tags: optics, cosmology, curvature, gravitational-lensing

If the large space voids between galaxies had uniformly-distributed "negative" gravitational lensing, would its presence be obvious from photos in the same way that the presence of Einstein crosses and Einstein rings make clear the existence of positive gravitational lensing?

Or would it only cause subtle distortions, such as reducing the angular diameters of distant galaxies as a function of their distance from us or by distorting how light transitions into and out of a positive gravitational lens?

If it would only cause the subtle effects (not obvious ones involving the inversion of images), is it possible for this effect to exist given what Hubble, Planck, etc. has received?